# Using a regex to find all lines that contain 3 or more words with consecutive identical letters

Tags: command-line, grep, regular-expression

An example of a matching line is: Gu**tt**er, Ru**bb**ing, Nomad, Among, Nit, Tu**rr**et, Tug

This line contains 3 words that all have 2 consecutive identical letters.

I'm currently using the following regex expression with the grep -P command: `(?:.*(?:(\w)\1).*){3}`.

This regex works but when I have the following line for example: `Gutter, Rutting, Nomad, Among, Nit, Turret, Tugekekekekekekekekekekeke` I get a catastrophic backtracking error on regex101.com (https://regex101.com/r/3YFCAj/1).

How can I search for this regex without that backtracking problem?

Comment: You don't need that first `.*`, which is what's causing the backtracking error on that site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Perl` style regex, that should work:

```
(\b\w*(\w)\2\w*\b.*){3}
```

Explanation:

- `(\w)\2` will match two identical consecutive characters. The `\2` will match the second matching group, which is the `(\w)` that precedes it.
- `\w*(\w)\2\w*` those characters should be inside a word with other word characters before and/or after.
- `\b\w*(\w)\2\w*\b` - and those words should be surrounded by word boundaries.
- `.*` - after each word we can have any other characters.
- `(\b\w*(\w)\2\w*\b.*){3}` - and finally this part should repeat 3 times to find at least 3 of those words.